# Defining comparator for sort function in c++ for pair objects

Tags: c++

Below is my code. The operat function is not working properly. Any help will be appreciated. Normally, `sort` sorts in ascending order. I want to define operat such that it sorts in descending order

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
typedef pair<int,pii> pwp;

bool operat(pwp a, pwp b){
    if(a.first > b.first){
        return true;
    }else if(a.second.first > b.second.first) {
        return true;

    }else if (a.second.second > b.second.second) { return true;}
    return false;

}
int main(){
    vector<pwp> inp;
    pwp obj1 = make_pair(1998,make_pair(3,24));
    pwp obj2 = make_pair(1998,make_pair(3,21));
    pwp obj3 = make_pair(1997,make_pair(3,24));
    inp.push_back(obj1);
    inp.push_back(obj2);
    inp.push_back(obj3);
    printf("Before sorting\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i< inp.size();i++){
        pwp sth = inp[i];
        printf("%d %d %d\n",sth.first,sth.second.first,sth.second.second);

    }
    sort(inp.begin(), inp.end(),operat);
    cout<<"After soring"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0 ; i< inp.size();i++){
        pwp sth = inp[i];
        printf("%d %d %d\n",sth.first,sth.second.first,sth.second.second);
    }
return 0;
}
```

New one:

```
bool operat(pwp a, pwp b){
    if(a.first > b.first){
        return true;
    }else if(a.first <  b.first) return false;

    else if(a.second.first > b.second.first) {
        return true;

    }else if (a.second.first < b.second.first) return false;
    else if (a.second.second > b.second.second) { return true;}
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Did you not *want* a strict order. If so, you nailed it.

Comment: Manu's answer spells it out, but just consider this, given any `a` and `b`, is there *any way* that `a > b` is false at the first tier, but true at any subsequent tier without the single-preconditon check of `a == b`? It may help to also consider this. standard comparisons consider `a == b` equates to  `!((a < b) || (b < a)`). Run some of your test data through that.

Comment: From who, me? I didn't down-vote your question. Dunno who did.

Comment: Well craig. can you pls vote it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
bool operat(pwp a, pwp b){
    if(a.first > b.first){
        return true;
    }else if(a.second.first > b.second.first) {
        return true;
    }else if (a.second.second > b.second.second) { return true;}
    return false;
}
```

the second comparison should only be performed if a.first == b.first and the third only if also a.second.first == b.second.first

Comment: @Programmer he didn't change your code. he told you exactly what was wrong with it (which is what you asked for in Juans answer). He was simply pointing out the code that has the error.

Comment: @Programmer: consider the comparison of (1, 2, 3) with (2, 1, 3): the intended answer is clearly `false`: the first value is not greater than the second. But your logic evaluates 1 > 2 as false, then the second `if` checks 2 > 1 and returns `true`.... manu-fatto has also told you how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

[std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) comes with comparison operators, which work if its template arguments have these operators. So you can simply use an [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) instance as comparison functor:

```
#include <functional> // for std::greater

operat = std::greater<pwp>();
std::sort(inp.begin(), inp.end(),operat);
```

If using `std::greater` is too daunting for whatever reason, then an alternative is do define function `operat` thus:

```
bool operat(const pwp& a, const pwp& b){ return a > b; }
```

If you insist on implement the lexical comparison logic yourself, then I would suggest the following: instead of thinking in terms of trying to figure out how to correctly compare `std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>`, figure out how to compare `std::pair<T1,T2>` in general. Then use that logic in the comparison of `std::pair<T1, std::pair<T2, t3>>`.

Comment: No. I want to know what is wrong with my code. i dont want to know alternate methods

Comment: @Programmer well, what's wrong with your code is that the comparison logic is all messed up. And the fix is to use `std::greater`. If you really want to re-invent the wheel, then I suggest writing a comparison for a single pair, and using that recursively.

Comment: Why -1 on this answer? please explain?

Comment: @billz it is probably too easy. Too hard to mess it up :-)

Comment: @Programmer I have added some suggestions. Basically, the approach is to "divide and conquer". That when you need a comparison for `std::pair<int, std::pair<int, std::pair<int,int>>>` you won't actually have to code anything.